# How to use unique factorization to show that the discriminant $d$ in the equation $(2ax_0+by_0)2=dy_0^2$ is indeed a perfect square?

Tags: number-theory

The theorem is from Niven's number theory "Binary quadratic forms" 3.4 Theorem 3.10 page 163-164

> Theorem $3.10 $:  Let $f(x, y) = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ be a binary quadratic form
> with integral coefficients and discriminant $d$. If $d \neq 0$ and $d$ is not a perfect square , then $a \neq 0, c \neq 0$, and the only solution of the equation $f(x, y) = 0$
> in integers is given by $x = y = 0$.
>
> Proof : We may presume that $a \neq 0$ and $c \neq 0$, for if $a = 0 $or $c = 0$ then
> $ac = 0$ and $d = b^2 - 4ac = b^2$, a perfect square. Suppose that $x_0$ and $y_0$
> are integers such that $f(x_0, y_0) = 0$. If $y_o = 0$ then $ax_0^2 = 0$, and hence
> $x_0 = 0$ because $a \neq 0$. If $x_0 = 0$, a parallel argument gives $y_0 = 0$. Consequently we take $x_0 \neq 0$ and $y_0 \neq 0$. By completing the square we see that
> $$4af( x, y) = (2ax + by)^2-dy^2$$
> and hence $(2ax_0 + by_0)^2 = dy_0^2$ since $f(x_0, y_0) = 0$. But $dy^2 \neq 0$, and **it
> follows by unique factorization that $d$ is a perfect square.** The proof is now
> complete

I am quite confused, why unique factorization would lead **d** be a perfect square?
It seems for me to prove **d** is indeed the perfect square we have to prove that $\frac{x_0}{y_0}$  is an integer, since
$$d=(\frac{(2ax_0+by_0)}{y_0})^2$$
and such fact doesn't have much to do with Unique factorization. Thank you for your advices!

Comment: This is a matter of style in proof by contradiction. If we say the assumption(s) are $x_0, y_0 \neq 0$  and $d\neq0$ also  not a square.  The contradiction  may come in more than one way. The lemma they are using is:  If  $u,v,w$   are nonzero integers   and $u^2 = v w^2,$  then $v$  is a square

Comment: @ Will Jagy, my understanding is that  we want to prove this theorem by contradiction, and we want to prove this theorem by showing that $x_0 \neq 0$ $y_0 \neq 0$ would leads to the contradiction that the discriminant d will be a square,  Is this understanding correct? If what I just said  is indeed correct, then the only thing I don't understand  is why  the last statement shows d is indeed a square, or  why the lemma which you showed is true.

Comment: As proved in the linked dupes (& *many* others) on irrationality of sqrts: if $\sqrt d$ is rational then it is integral.

Comment: Proofs typically use properties intimately connected to unique prime factorization (e.g. properties of gcds). This result may fail in domains without unique factorization, e.g. in quadratic number rings, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3028585/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2098999/242).

Comment: @Bill Dubuque， Then for similar theorem in such quadrtic rings which unique factorization property fails , Is such similar theorem still holds even without the property of unique factorization? If it is, which proof strategy is commonly use?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3838233/242) for citations on *root closed* domains.

Answer (score -1):

First you prove the following result about greatest common divisor:

**Fact 1:**

If $p, q \in \mathbb{N}$ and if $(p,q) = 1$, then $(p^2,q^2) = 1$.

**Proof:**
We use Bezout's theorem for this.
That is there exists integers $s,t \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that: $sp+tq = 1$. Square both sides: $s^2p^2+2stpq + t^2q^2 = 1 \implies s^2p^2+2stpq(sp+tq) + t^2q^2 = 1$. Rewrite to obtain: $s^2p^2+ 2s^2tqp^2+2st^2pq^2+t^2q^2 = 1$, and this gives: $(s^2+2s^2tq)p^2+(2st^2p+t^2)q^2 = 1$. By Bezout's theorem, $(p^2,q^2) = 1$. Now use this result to prove one more result, namely:

**Fact 2:**

If $a \in \mathbb{Q}$, and $a^2 \in \mathbb{N}$ then $a \in \mathbb{N}$.

**Proof:** For if $a \notin \mathbb{N}$, then since $a \in \mathbb{Q}$, we can write $a = \dfrac{p}{q}$ where $(p,q) = 1$ and $p, q \in \mathbb{N}$. First we show: $q = 1$. Suppose $q \neq 1$, then $a^2 = \dfrac{p^2}{q^2}\implies p^2 = a^2q^2\implies (p^2,q^2) \ge q^2 > 1$, contradiction to fact 1. Thus $q = 1$. Hence $a = p \in \mathbb{N}$.

You have: $d = \left(\dfrac{2ax_0+by_0}{y_0}\right)^2 = a^2 \in \mathbb{N}\implies a = \dfrac{2ax_0+by_0}{y_0} \in \mathbb{N}$ by fact 2. Thus $d = a^2$ which is a perfect square.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: This proof is different from those that were posted few years ago though.

Comment: The above common proofs are given here tens (if not hundreds) of times already. There is nothing new above.

Comment: @ Bill Dubuque, Then should I delete this question?

Comment: If there is a improved and easier to follow, then it is regarded as a good question, my thought is keep it posted. Of course, this question is very old, but sometimes a better way to explain it is worth seeing....

Comment: But there is nothing "better" above - only duplication of very well known basic results.

Comment: Actually, the other proofs are not better though. Hehehe. They just "go off tangent"....